# How to load datatable showing only max revision

Tags: jquery, datatables

Do you have any inputs on how I can load my datatables showing only the record with the latest revision?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({

  });
});
```

The above script show all records.
Appreciate your help.

If I have the working code, I will use these code to switch between max revision only to show all records by using toogle button.

Comment: Sort the table, then hide all but the first row. Or, if the data is coming from the server via AJAX, just return the single required record from the endpoint

Comment: Can you suggest a code for that? I'll be switching max revision to all record using toggle button.